# How does the ToString work with indexers?

Tags: c#, indexing, tostring

I have the following code:

```
int age = 47; 
int firstDigit = age.ToString()[0];
Console.WriteLine($"firstDigit: { firstDigit }");
```

If I run these code I get the value of `52` for firstDigit. 
What happens in this code to get the value 52?

And how can I have the correct first digit (=4) of age?

Comment: Btw.: a faster way (about 50%) would be `int firstDigit = age; while ((firstDigit / 10) > 0) { firstDigit /= 10; }` (benchmarked with 5000 random non-negative integer values).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

52 is the ascii value of for 4. To get `4`, you want this:

```
int age = 47; 
char firstDigit = age.ToString()[0];
Console.WriteLine($"firstDigit: { firstDigit }");
```

Remember, there is a big difference between the number four and the character value '4'. If you really want the number four, you can do this:

```
int age = 47; 
int firstDigit = age.ToString()[0] - '0';
Console.WriteLine($"firstDigit: { firstDigit }");
```

It relies on the idea that whatever character system you're using, the digits will always be represented in sequence starting with 0.

Comment: Thank you, for your answer. I didn't know that ToString converts it to an ascii code. Now that I know this it is logical that it prints 52.

Comment: @Jarne `ToString()` converts the _entire number_ to a string, because  _**of course**_ it does; that's what the name says. Then, when you look any single indexed position of a string, you have a **character**. In this case, the character value is still `'4'`. It's assigning that character to an integer variable that gives you an ascii code.

Answer (score 1):

52 is the UNICODE / ASCII value for the number 4, what you're really doing is converting the age to a string "47" and getting the first character "4" as an integer which would be 52 - just use char to stick with the "4"

Answer (score 0):

Parse it to string:

```
int age = 47;
Console.Write(age.ToString()[0]);
```